# Why does the cartesian product of two two-dimensional figures lie in the three-dimensional space?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

So, here is the question. Assume we have two circles. They lie in the two-dimensional space. The cartesian product of the sets representing two circles consists of 4-tuples, and thus, one may expect a geometric representation of that set in the fourth-dimensional space. Indeed, one may consider the cartesian product of a line (one-dimensional space) and a circle (two-dimensional space) as a cylindrical surface (one plus two, thus three-dimensional space). However, for two circles, one may come up with the torus representation, which seems intuitively reasonable. So, what makes two circles special in this case, and is there a general rule which allows us to determine whether there is a representation in a space of a lower dimension than the sum dimension?

P.S. I'm not sure about the tags. Sorry if they're misleading.

Comment: You should learn some basic topology in order to formulate more precise questions along these lines. I think what you are asking is for a necessary/sufficient conditions for the product of two planar sets to be topologically embeddable in $R^3$.

Comment: The fact that both circles are 1 dimensional makes it plausible, but even that is not enough. Consider an X shape. The product of it with itself is not embeddable in 3 dimensions because of the local structure around the intersection point.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan, ok, I will. I don't study topology or something related. I was just curious. Someone changed the tags to include general topology, but I hardly expected it would be so complicated. Thank you.

Comment: @Cheerful Parsnip, very interesting! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is actually complicated when stated properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem#Restrictions_on_manifolds):

If $N$ is a compact orientable $n$-dimensional manifold, then $N$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}^{ 2 n − 1}$.

Comment: Wow, it seems the question that arose from my curiosity is not so stupid :)

Comment: It’s not a stupid question at all! It’s a great question.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip The last sentence of the question asks for  properties that guarantee an embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{2n-1}$. Whitney's theorem provides one. This answer quotes that theorem, with a reference. Proving it here is out of the question.

Comment: @EthanBolker but the OP was explicitly asking about products (OP says "sum dimension"). For manifolds which are subsets of the plane, this really only applies to products of 1 -manifolds, which is nothing additional to what the OP already knows.